# How can I find out what app has been blocked by my administrator in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, uac, blocking

My workplace has blocked the Microsoft Store and various other apps from running on our laptops for security reasons. I have no issues with that but I have noticed every so often when I unlock my laptop after being away from some time I get the "This app has been blocked by your system administrator" as soon as I return. Very frequently, I get it twice - once I dismiss the first prompt I get the second one immediately.

[image]

The thing is I have no idea what's actually being blocked. The dialog gives no indication as to what the offending app was, the "Copy to Clipboard" button just copies the same error message, and I can't find it in any logs or anything either. I'm not the only one in the company who has experienced this and the IT staff doesn't know what causes it either.

How can I find out what app is triggering this? It's not impeding my work but I'm curious what is happening and what can be done to stop causing the prompt.

Comment: Have a look in Event Viewer under AppLocker. Otherwise you'll need to have a word with your network admin. (Event Viewer -> Applications and Services -> Microsoft -> Windows -> AppLocker)

Comment: You may have scheduled tasks that run when the computer is idle. Check the action and see if they are blocked when you execute them. You can also disable the task to see if the messages disappear.

Comment: You need an administrator account for finding this. Do you have such an account?